# Post notice does not appear in Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, post-notices

Currently there's a reddit post notice on the desktop and mobile version of [How to pass "Null" (a real surname!) to a SOAP web service in ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456438/how-can-i-pass-the-string-null-through-wsdl-soap-from-actionscript-3-to-a-co) for the redditors visiting the question. But in the Android app, the notice is absent completely. They probably should be displayed in the Android app in some fashion?

<sub>using v0.1.64</sub>

Comment: I'm actually quite amazed by the lack of off-topic comments on that question. (Unless there's a mod sitting there right now deleting them within seconds before I can see them.) Maybe that post notice actually does work.